# How to stop modules or services being exported that are not in the public-api.ts file

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I would like to know how I can force my libraries/projects to only use files from other libraries that are exported specifically by those other libraries.

What I am actually looking for is that vscode will not show any references of services/interfaces that are available from any library, if said library did not export those services/interfaces expressly.

Scenario 1:
Lets say that I have a file of interfaces in library1 that I export so that other services in library1 can use them, but I do not export them in library1's public-api.ts file.
Is it possible to make intellisense not show them as options to use when I am in library2, and I type a interface name like/similar to one in the interface file of library1?

Scenario 2:
Same as scenario 1, but this time I do export the interface file in the public-api.ts file, and now they should show up in library2 when I am typing an interface

Comment: Have you found a answer for this? I want to only expose the files under `public-api.ts`

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I still need this though, so if you find anything be sure to answer it here.

Comment: I haven't found a time for this one, but you can take a look at how https://nx.dev/ 's approach is. If i remember it correctly, they were able to do just like this one.